# mongo sort by group criteria

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have data structure like this (mongo 2.6):

```
{"player":"John Doe","active":true}
```

lets say I use the term "ohn" when performing search, I need to sort based on certain criteria:

1. players whose name is "ohn" AND active
2. players whose name CONTAINS "ohn" AND active
3. players whose name is "ohn" but NOT active
4. players whose name CONTAINS "ohn" but NOT active

how do I achieve this in mongo 2.6?
the expected output is all players who meets any of those 4 criteria, but sorted in that order (players who meet crit 1, then players who meet crit 2, and so on). I also want to add pagination (skip and limit)
thanks

Comment: can you add expected output.

Comment: @RahulSharma I expect a list of players who meets any of those 4 criteria, but sorted in that order, 1 to 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I create addition columns call point for sorting

1. active = true give 2 point
2. whole player contain word give 1 point

And sort result by point descending. Here is query

```
    db.yourtable.aggregate(
        [ 
             { $match : { "player": /ohn/i } } /* select all contain ohn ignore case */
            ,{ $project:{
                player: 1,
                active: 1,
                point: { $add: [ 
                                {$cond: { if: { $eq: [ "$active", true ] }, then: 2, else: 0 }}                      /* active = true give 2 point */
                                , {$cond: { if: { $eq: [ { $toLower: "$player" }, 'ohn' ] }, then: 1, else: 0 }}     /* player contain whole word give 1 point */
                        ]}

                }
            }
            ,{ $sort : { point : -1 } }  /* sort by point */
        ]
    );
```

I ignore case sensitive, hope this help

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**, Hope this will help.

```
db.getCollection('TEST').find({}).sort({"active":-1}).toArray().reduce(function(doc1, doc2) {
    if(doc2.player == "ohn" && doc2.active)
        doc1.unshift(doc2)
    else
        doc1.push(doc2)
  return doc1; 
},[]);
```

Comment: is it possible to use aggregation instead of map reduce? thanks

Comment: this is for exact match only? not partial match?

Comment: I'm not sure, aggregation will work for custom order and condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.aggregate(

    // Pipeline
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $match: {
                $or: [{
                    $text: {
                        $search: "ohn"
                    }
                }, {
                    player: /ohn/i
                }],
                active: {
                    $in: [true, false]
                }
            }
        },

        // Stage 2
        {
            $sort: {
                active: -1
            }
        },

    ]



);
```

In above mentioned aggregate query text search is performed to filter and sort documents from MongoDB collection according to criteria mentioned into description of question.

Text Index needs to be applied to fields which needs to be filtered to perform text based search into MongoDB collection.

Comment: what about the sorting of the results? this seems only sort by active, no sorting based on exact match or partial match. sorting must be done first by active, and then by exact or partial match, so, 2 fields

Comment: Above query  sorts results into descending order of active field and upon applying text search it returns results into order of nearest matching value